# How can I print from Android phone through Google Chrome connected printer in laptop?

Tags: printing

I have a printer connected to laptop. The printer does not have any network features such as Apple AirPort but connected to a laptop with Google Chrome. My Android phone is also running Google Chrome. Both the phone and laptop are under the same account.

How can I print through the Android phone to the printer? Can I do it with Google Cloud -printing?

Comment: I fear it's not possible.  I just searched for "print" in the Nexus 7 manual, and came up with nothing.  I dimly recall that, a while ago, a few Android apps, in limited circumstances, could use Google Cloud Printing; but I guess that was an experiment that's since been cancelled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43774/how-to-print-to-cups-running-on-another-computer-in-the-lan

Comment: Apple uses CUPS.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it should work with Google Cloud Print.

From: https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?rd=1

1. Log in to your user account on the Windows, Mac, or Linux computer.
2. Open Google Chrome.
3. Click the wrench icon  on the browser toolbar.
4. Select Settings.
5. Click the Show advanced settings link.
6. Scroll down to the “Google Cloud Print” section. Click Sign in to
   Google Cloud Print.  In the window that appears, sign in with your
   Google Account to enable the Google Cloud Print connector.

   [image]
7. A printer confirmation message appears and click Finish printer
   registration. You'll see a confirmation that Google Cloud Print has
   been enabled. Click Manage your printers to learn more.

Now when you have something to print, for example: some document in Google Drive, hit print button and your printer should show up. But your laptop must be on all the time and connected to printer.

Answer (score 0):

Apple and Linux use what is called [CUPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS). Because your laptop is Apple, you should be able to set the printer as "shared" on your laptop and then, install an app such as [Lets Print Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blackspruce.lpd) that is CUPS compatible.

After you install the app, swipe down and click on the notification to enable the print service. Your printer should automatically be discovered. If not, you may have to "add printer".

I use the lets print droid app installed on my android device along with [google cups-connector](https://github.com/google/cups-connector) installed on my laptop so you may need that as well but I don't believe google cups-connector is needed.

I can now print from my chrome browser in android as a local printer, no cloud.

[thank's to @barton for this similar answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/100821/119313)